# FragmentManger findFragmentById returns null after screen orientation change

Tags: android, fragment

I have a problem with getting the current fragment after the screen has been rotated.

I have a sync service which reports the progress to `MainActivity` which in turns passes the data to a `SyncFragment` if that Fragment is currently committed.

However, if the screen has been rotated during the sync the `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.crossfade_content)` returns null, even though SyncFragment is still committed and visible, and MainActivity is then unable to report any progress to SyncFragment and the screen is just stuck on loading even though the sync has been completed.

I would like to avoid using `android:configChanges` since it should be a last resort, and I don't want to use it for one small problem which could cause me issues further down the road.

**This is how the process looks**

First the SyncFragment gets committed and from there the sync service is started.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.crossfade_content, SyncFragment.newInstance(true))
        .commit();
```

Sync service then reports to MainActivity which is turns reports to SyncFragment if it's currently active.

```
@Override
public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData)
{
    //…

    //Report progress to SyncFragment if it is active
    Fragment fragment = getCurrentFragment();
    if (getCurrentFragment() instanceof SyncFragment)
    {
        SyncFragment syncFragment = (SyncFragment)fragment;
        syncFragment.reportSyncProgress(resultCode, resultData);
    }
}
```

During the sync the screen is then rotated by the user, and SyncFragment is still visible and is in loading mode.

```
@Override
public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData)
{
    //…

    //Report progress to SyncFragment if it is active
    Fragment fragment = getCurrentFragment(); // <-- This is now returning null
    if (getCurrentFragment() instanceof SyncFragment)
    {
        SyncFragment syncFragment = (SyncFragment)fragment;
        syncFragment.reportSyncProgress(resultCode, resultData);
    }
}
```

Since `getCurrentFragment()` is now returning null the data can no longer be passed to the fragment even though it's visible, and it is now stuck on loading.

**Edit - further research**

So when the screen is rotated then MainActivity onCreate is called as normal. Calling `getCurrentFragment()` in `onCreate` will return SyncFragment as you would expect, because that fragment is still committed.

However, up in `onReceiveResult` (which is called after onCreate) the same function (`getCurrentFragment()`) returns null.

Additionally, `onAttachFragment` does get called when screen is rotated, and the SyncFragment is passed to that function like it is expected. However for some reason if I use the reference to that fragment after screen is rotated I get the error that the Fragment is not attached to a context.

**Edit - more**

If I put the `getCurrentFragment()` on a button click and click it after a screen rotation, it returns SyncFragment. Only in onActivityResult the method returns null.

Comment: @PankajKumar but the fragment is already displaying. Do I still need to re-attach it? Seems unnecessary to refresh it.

Comment: No no. there may be other reason which I am missing here. Wait for someone :)

Comment: @PankajKumar I added the whole process, maybe it could give better insight.

Comment: @PankajKumar I added more code, comments and research. Could you take a look again?

Comment: Are you calling unbindService in onDestroy?

Comment: @Karacken no, I don't call bindService either. The service is started through Intent from the SyncFragment fragment. Is that bad practise?

Comment: I could re-commit the fragment on onRestoreInstanceState but since the SyncFragment is already committed and in place after a screen rotation, it feels like I shouldn't need to commit it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem was the ResultReceiver.**

After the activity has been re-created the ResultReceiver was unable to properly report back, so the solution was to save its state.

This wasn't an obvious solution looking back at my question, but if some lone wanderer runs into the same problem as mine, then here is the solution.

Save the state of the ResultReceiver when the screen orientation changes.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    //…

    outState.putParcelable("receiver", _syncReceiver);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Load it up again on onCreate

```
if (savedInstanceState != null)
    _syncReceiver = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("receiver");

if (_syncReceiver == null)
    _syncReceiver = new SyncResultReceiver(new Handler());

_syncReceiver.setReceiver(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

When screen orientation is changed existing activity gets destroyed and gets recreated after it. If you want to retain a fragment you can use below code in onCreate of your Fragment, then you will get its instance even after orientation gets change:

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

Comment: Much like android:configChanges this seems like a band-aid to an otherwise solvable problem. The fragment does get recreated and committed properly. I just can't get the reference to it.